# IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, exception, null, kotlin

I'm getting the following **runtime error**:

```
 checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter oneClickTokens
    at com.info.app.fragments.Fragment_Payment_Profile$fetchMerchantHashes$1.onPostExecute(Fragment_Payment_Profile.kt:0)
    at com.info.app.fragments.Fragment_Payment_Profile$fetchMerchantHashes$1.onPostExecute(Fragment_Payment_Profile.kt:1543)
```

Here's **my code**:

```
 private fun fetchMerchantHashes(intent: Intent) {
    // now make the api call.
    val postParams = "merchant_key=$key&user_credentials=$var1"
    val baseActivityIntent = intent
    object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String, String>>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): HashMap<String, String>? {
                ...
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(oneClickTokens: HashMap<String, String>) {
            super.onPostExecute(oneClickTokens)
            ...

        }
    }.execute()
}
```

It seems that the function call seems to be invalid. However, I don't know how to fix this problem. Is there anything Kotlin specific I've missed?

Comment: There is no question. Please formulate one to get help.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear: you're passing `null` for the parameter.

By default all variables and parameters in **Kotlin** are non-null. If you want to pass `null` parameter to the method you should add `?` to it's type, for example:

```
fun fetchMerchantHashes(intent: Intent?)
```

*For more information: [null-safety](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).*

Comment: I experienced the same problem and I had to read Kotlin documentation. Kind of knew what was wrong in my code, but for further to clarify what I understood from Kotlin documentation, I end up coming to this page, I found your answer matching exactly with what I thought. Your answer is clear and concise.

Answer (score 4):

In my case this error warned about *probable* passing a null as a parameter. Three ways of correction.

1. Change a type of a parameter in corresponding place. If it is received from Java, add `@NonNull` annotation to a variable definition.
2. Add `!!` to an argument of the method.
3. Add `?` to the parameter in Kotlin class. I think, Kotlin conversion tool might do this by default, if in Java class there were no annotations used (like `@Nullable`, `@NonNull`).

Comment: errors are not warnings and warnings are not errors. Adding !! can cause a NullPointerException merely because you are asserting at runtime it is non-null when it is actually null.

Comment: @ezaspi, agree with you. I will add a `?` case. In the past I set `!!` to see a crash in runtime, where NPE could happen.

Comment: We just finished a large Android to Kotlin refactor and those pesky !! were worse than possible nulls that existed previously. Example, a call to method abc(String somevalue) in Android gets converted to Kotlin (by converter) to abc(somevalue: String!!). Before conversion, abc handled nulls, but after immediately throws a NPE. One may argue we should have had a @Nullable but it was a large project, and so didn't catch them all.  And it only takes one of those to crash the app.

Comment: Btw, if it were just our code it wouldn't be so bad. But a lot of Android overrides don't have @Nullable annotations. So after the auto-converter gets done, the code may have this:     `override fun onItemSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>, selectedItemView: View, position: Int, id: Long)`                                  But it should be a nullable View? as this often crashes

Comment: @ezaspi, I totally agree with you and also faced these problems many times. That's a disadvantage of the auto-converter. Sorry, I wrote this answer a year ago when started to learn Kotlin.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Answer Will Work For Sure...
When you are fetching the data from the Server using Rest Client (Web Services calls) (GET Or POST) and if there could be a null parameter value in the json response, and you are fetching the parameter and appending it to textview you get this error..

**Solution:**
    just append ? mark to the variable as below..

**Example:**

```
var batchNo: String? = "" (Correct Approach)
var batchNo= "" (Will Get Error)
```

Here I am trying to fetch batchNo using service call.

Answer (score 1):

I caught similar exception after converting an Activity from Java to Kotlin using Android Studio converting tool. So, it's that I got `override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent)`

It's right `override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)`

Difference in `intent: Intent?`

Comment: Yes, it often happens in old Java classes that don't use `@Nullable` annotation. Kotlin conversion tool doesn't know, how to recognize this parameter and guess it is not null (that is a mistake). In Swift, if you convert from Objective-C, it will guess it can be nil.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the binding adapters, change the type of the item argument to nullable, and wrap the body with

> item?.let{...}

[source](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interacting-with-items#4) in google documentation