# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null firebase transaction kotlin

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to increment an integer in Firebase database but, the app crashes.

```
abstract class BrowserActivity : ThemableBrowserActivity(),OnClickListener {

        private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null 

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            BrowserApp.appComponent.inject(this)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            incrementId() //calling the function increment id
        }

        protected fun incrementId() {
                 val cUser = mAuth?.currentUser
                 val uid: String = cUser!!.uid    
                 var databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid).child("id")


                 databaseReference!!.runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
                        override fun doTransaction(mutableData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
                            var count = mutableData.getValue(Int::class.java)
                            if (count == null) {
                                mutableData.setValue(1)
                            } else {
                                mutableData.setValue(count+1)
                            }
                            return Transaction.success(mutableData)
                        }

                        override fun onComplete(databaseError: DatabaseError, b: Boolean, dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {}
                    })
                }
        }
```

Logcat:

> 10-01 22:30:34.227 14674-14674/in.brew.meteor E/FileUtils: Unable to write bundle to storage
>   10-01 22:30:34.228 14674-14674/in.brew.meteor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: in.brew.meteor, PID: 14674
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter databaseError
>           at in.brew.meteor.browser.activity.BrowserActivity$saveData$1.onComplete(BrowserActivity.kt)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecm.run(Unknown Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Database structure:

```
my-firebase-app-name-9c826
   |__-users
         |_-FZTuHfNiXoSWOLiNlSv9w1vVZj03  //uid: user id of current user
                 |__id: 1
```

[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHVkF.png)

My Firebase rules:
`My Firebase rules:

`{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}`

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @Alex Mamo Added the database structure.

Comment: How is the `uid` that you have used here: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid).child("id")` declared ? Please add the code that are using to instantiate the `uid`.

Comment: Please check I have added few lines.

Comment: I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885783/illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null/44885870) post, I am passing `databaseError` as `null` to `onComplete`.
By default all variables in kotlin are non null. So, if I want to pass a `null` parameter,
I have to add a `?` to the parameter, which in my case should be `DatabaseError?`. So the `onComplete` function should look like:

`override fun onComplete(databaseError: DatabaseError?, b: Boolean, dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {}`